# cAkeneo product image relations Mother >< Child

Tags: image, magento, magento2, akeneo, pim

I am on Magento 2 with Akeneo community editdion.

We are creating family relations for products in PIM, connecting simple products to product models. The variants can be size or color (or both).

My question is;
Since a "mother" (product model) does not have an image, unless we add one manually. These products will not be shown in frontend. Our fix is to also add pictures to Configurable products.

I am pretty sure this is not how this is ment to work. I expect that CMS/PIM would display the product variant in stock. or perhaps is new?

*(What if we keep adding images manually to all configurable products.. They could eventually be sold out, or new color variants added. These main images will then be old, not relevant, inaccurate...) *

Anyone else having the same issue? or solution?

I want our CMS to display product pictures from variants in stock. Using Akeneo PIM as the tool to enrich product variants and product models.

I need configurable products to find and use main image based upon the variants connected.
For example; a shirt model (configuarble product) can have 5 different colours, but same SKU.

It does not make any sense that we manually upload pictures to both simple and configurable products. And if uploaded to configurable product in CMS, it will just be deleted over night when next sync job is done.